# Invalid resx file: Root element missing

Tags: c#, xna

Okay so, I'm making a C# game and have inserted some background images on a form. My PC Crashed (all work was saved beforehand) and I went to reboot Visual Studio (2013) to find these errors on the project:

Message 1

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041FEB     0   0

Warning 2

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Error   3

> Invalid Resx file. Root element is missing.    C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fazbearmuseum\fazbearmuseum\Game.resx  fazbearmuseum

I also noticed the resources folder in the project directory was missing.

Any help? I've already spent an hour of research finding nothing!

**EDIT:** Warning 2 has been fixed. I changed the Debug platform target to x86

**EDIT 2:** I've come to a conclusion that Error 3 is causing Message 1. But how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I already had the Error #3, the xml structure of the file had been corrupted by a forbidden character.

Maybe this is not exactly the same problem, but I suggest you open the resx file with an xml text editor and validate the xml structure.

Comment: Not supported. Also when I open the file by just double clicking on it in the solution explorer, it shows me a bunch of hex data.

Answer (score 0):

The designer is now visible again! I solved this by deleting the whole resource file. It worked, but also removed all the background images I put on the form (as expected). All my controls were kept, and I can simply add these images again.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the resx file was empty, I have put at least single string to build correctly